# Getting an error when executing this shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu

The error i'm getting is line 30 warning: here-document at line 10 delimited by end of file ('wanted simple.sh'). What does this error mean?
Here is what line 10 looks like.

```
cat <<simple.sh | grep '^[^abc]$.*!$' >>Result
```

I'm trying to append the output of simple.sh to the file Result.

Comment: The error is on line 30 but you’re showing us line 10?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Line 30 is probably the end of the script.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax

```
somecommand <<TAG
```

starts a here-document.  A here-document is a type of input redirection of a text block.  The contents of the here-document is ended when `TAG` is encountered on a line by itself.  For example:

```
cat <<END_TEXT
this is
some text
END_TEXT
```

The tag can be any word, and in your case, the word is `simple.sh`, and the shell complains that it can't find the word that would end the here-document.

What I presume you meant is

```
cat simple.sh | grep ... >>Result
```

or

```
cat <simple.sh | grep ... >>Result
```

or just

```
grep ... simple.sh >>Result
```

---

Also note that the regular expression `^[^abc]$.*!$` can *never* match as there is no single line with a `!` *after* the end of the line.

Comment: `cat` can probably also be removed entirely. `grep [whatever] simple.sh >> result` should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Thegs Yes. Added that.